# If statement to check element click won't be intercepted (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code waits for an element to be clickable, but even when this occurs there is still a popup box above it that remains for a few seconds while a table is populated. This means my click is getting intercepted.

Is there a way to run an if statement to say 'if click will be intercepted, `time.sleep(1)` then try again? I don't really want to use a simple `time.sleep(3)` on its own as the time to load will vary and I'd like to be efficient.

Current code is just the initial step:

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "location-expandable-click")))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best is to wait until popup box will disappear. You can use wait with `invisibility_of_element_located` for that.

Second option is to use JavaScript to click:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "location-expandable-click"))))
```

Third, use [Try Except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp):

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "location-expandable-click")))
clicked = False
for _ in range(5):
    try:
        element.click()
        clicked = True
        break
    except ElementClickInterceptedException as e:
        print("Failed to click, will try again after 1 second")
        time.sleep(1)

if not clicked:
    print("Failed to click after 5 tries")
```

Comment: thank you for this! I tried the second option (javascript) and it worked!